# Move constructor not getting called, instead copy constructor gets called

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

I am trying to call the move constructor but the copy constructor is getting called.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class X
{
    char* name;
public:
    X(const char* p)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
        strcpy(name, p);
        std::cout<<"Constructor: "<<name<<"; Address: "<<this<<std::endl;
    }

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destructor: "<<name<<"; Address: "<<this<<std::endl;
        delete [] name;
    }

    X(const X& a)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, a.name);
        std::cout<<"Copy Constructor: "<<name<<"; Address: "<<this<<"; made from: "<<&a<<std::endl;
    }

    X& operator=(const X& a)
    {
        if (name)
        {
            delete [] name;
        }

        name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, a.name);
        std::cout<<"Assignment operator: "<<name<<"; Address: "<<this<<"; made from: "<<&a<<std::endl;

        return *this;
    }

    X operator+(const X& a)
    {
        std::string s1 = name;
        std::string s2 = a.name;
        s1.append(" ");
        s1.append(s2);

        X x(s1.c_str());

        std::cout<<"operator+: "<<s1.c_str()<<"; Address: "<<&x<<"; Created from"
            <<this<<" and "<<&a<<std::endl;

        return x;
    }

    // move copy constructor
    X(X&& a)
    {
        name = a.name;
        a.name = nullptr;
        std::cout<<"Move Copy Constructor: "<<name<<"; Address: "<<this<<std::endl;
    }

    friend X fun(const X& a);
};

X fun(const X& a)
{
    std::cout<<"Inside fun()"<<std::endl;
    X p = a;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    X h("Harry");
    X r("Ron");

    std::cout<<"Trying to create a temporary object"<<std::endl;
    X a = fun(h + r);
    std::cout<<"Check above if a temporay object was created"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

O/P of the above program:

```
Constructor: Harry; Address: 0x79315dbc31b0
Constructor: Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31c0
Trying to create a temporary object
Constructor: Harry Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31e0
operator+: Harry Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31e0; Created from0x79315dbc31b0 and 0x79315dbc31c0
Inside fun()
Copy Constructor: Harry Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31d0; made from: 0x79315dbc31e0
Destructor: Harry Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31e0
Check above if a temporay object was created
Destructor: Harry Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31d0
Destructor: Ron; Address: 0x79315dbc31c0
Destructor: Harry; Address: 0x79315dbc31b0
```

Does it mean the program is not able to create a temporary object?
I thought the object with address 0x79315dbc31e0 was a temporary object.

Note: Since my gcc is old I tried this code on one of the online C++ compilers that support C++11 and C++14.

Comment: The return value of `h + r` is a temporary object.  What was unexpected about the output? Where do you think you are "trying to call the move constructor" ?

Comment: I was expecting "X a = fun(h + r);" to call the move copy constructor.

Comment: In that line `a` is moved from the return value of `fun`, but this is also a copy-elision context. `X p` inside `fun` is identified with `X a = fun(h+r);`. If you compile with copy elision disabled you should see the move constructor call.

Comment: Ok, will try that...problem is the online compiler doesn't give the option to disable copy-elision. Also will research a bit on copy-elision. Thanks a lot M.M!

Comment: Unrelated, but `operator=` should check for self-assignment

Comment: The copy constructor call is from `X p = a;`  - `a` is copied to `p`.  This would be in addition to any move constructor call (not a replcement as you suggest in the title)

Comment: @M.M an `operator=` that checks for self-assignment is a buggy self-assignment, because the implementation isn't exception safe. An exception safe copy assignment doesn't need that check.

Comment: @MooingDuck It would be exception-safe if the `new[]` is done before the `delete[]`

Comment: @M.M, I thought `X p = a;` should have called the move constructor. Isn't `a` the temporary here?

Comment: @Saket `a` designates a temporary object, but `a` is an lvalue (all named variables are lvalues), so `X&&` does not bind to it.  (Rvalue-references cannot bind to lvalues). Also, you cannot fix this by writing `p = std::move(a);` because `a` was declared `const`.  If you want to move out of the temporary object then you cannot bind a const reference to the temporary object. You would have to instead use `X fun(X a);` (fun can be called with lvalues and rvalues), or `X fun(X&& a);` (fun can only be called with rvalues).

Comment: @M.M I tried by changing 'fun()' to - `X fun(X&& a);` .. still the o/p is same. Of course I was not able to disable copy-elision.

Comment: You also need to change `X p = a;` to `X p = std::move(a);` .  The copy elision we are taking about is in the `return p;`  . Initially you said that you thought `X a = fun(h+r)` was the move operation, but now you say you thought it was the `X p = a;`

Comment: @M.M, `X p = std::move(a);` worked. I actually meant `X p = a;`, dunno why I wrote `X a = fun(h+r)`. Thanks!

Comment: @M.M: if `new[]` is before the `delete[]`, it is indeed exception safe...and no longer needs a check for self assignment.

Comment: @MooingDuck The self-assignment check would be an optimization in that case. I guess you could argue it's actually a pessimization, if self-assignment rarely occurs for your object in the program

Comment: @M.M that's exactly it

Answer (score 2):

The call to the "Copy Constructor", immediately after "Inside fun()", is actually the call to the copy constructor from the following line, in `fun()`:

```
X p = a;
```

That's the call to the copy constructor. You were obviously expecting a move constructor to be invoked as a result of:

```
X a = fun(h + r);
```

This temporary is completely "elided" away. This entire sequence:

```
X p = a;
return p;
```

Results in the compiler essentially constructing `p` as the return value from the function, so "return p" does nothing.

Then, because the return value from the function gets used to instantiate the `a` object in main(), the caller essentially passes main()'s "a", to `fun()`, as the object to be constructed by `fun()`.

You can see for yourself, the sequence of these events, simply by stepping through your code with the debugger.

Comment: I thought `X p = a;` should have called the move constructor. Isn't `a` the temporary here?

Comment: No, 'a' is not a temporary. 'a' is a fully-qualified parameter to this function. 'h+r' is a temporary, in the context of its expression. But, inside the function, 'a' is a discrete object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what is "discrete object"? `a` designates a temporary object.